# Computer not booting after I tripped on power cord, just the fan keeps making insane noise

Tags: power-supply, power

I accidentally tripped on my ubuntu machine power cable. Since then I am not able to boot the computer, even the bios doesn't load. Whenever I turn it on, after a 30 seconds or so, the fan starts making a lot of noise. Monitor shows no signal, but the DVD tray seems to have power.

Does power failure put the computer into some special mode, which I need to change? Any ideas?

Comment: Check all your cables. Better yet, detach and reattach all your cables

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure I understand. There is only one power cable for my computer. Are you talking about any internal power cables?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have caused a physical impact to the computer by tripping over the power cable. Perhaps the fan is misaligned or a grill dented. Perhaps some internal cables or other components have come loose.

I would

- Unplug the power, open the case and inspect for any signs of physical damage or loose cables and components.
- repair or replace any components physically damaged.
- Reseat memory and PCIe cards etc.

Comment: Thanks! Only the power cable got disconnected when I tripped over the cable. There was no movement whatsoever of the computer cabinet.  Therefore, I am not sure what you mean by physical damage here. Could you please clarify?